# $ \vec u = (a, b, c) , \vec v = (b, a, 3) , \vec u . \vec v = {\vert u \vert}^2 , \vert \vec u - \vec v \vert = 5, c = ?$

Tags: vectors

$\vec u . \vec v = {\vert \vec u \vert}^2$

$\vert \vec u - \vec v \vert = 5$

Using these identities

$\vec u . \vec v = \vert \vec u \vert . \vert \vec v \vert . \cos \theta$

${\vert \vec u + \vec v \vert }^2 - 2 \vert \vec u \vert . \vert \vec v \vert . \cos \theta = {\vert \vec u \vert}^2 + {\vert \vec v \vert}^2 $

without expanding $\vec u . \vec v  = ab + ab + 3c$ and $ \vec u - \vec v  = (a-b , b - a, c - 3)$ how do i continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\vec u = (a, b, c) , \vec v = (b, a, 3) , \vec u . \vec v = {\vert u \vert}^2 , \vert \vec u - \vec v \vert = 5, c = ?$$

$$\vec u . \vec v=ab+ba+3c$$

$${\vert u \vert}^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$$
$$|\vec u - \vec v |^2=(a-b)^2+(b-a)^2+(3-c)^2$$

We have $$2ab+3c=a^2+b^2+c^2$$
$$2(a-b)^2+(3-c)^2=25$$

or 
$$3c-c^2=(a-b)^2$$
$$2(a-b)^2+(3-c)^2=25$$
Subtract twice the first equation to the second.

$$(3-c)^2=25-2c(3-c)$$
or 
$$-16-c^2=0$$

you can conclude

Comment: There is an error in the step $2(a-b)^2+(3-c)^2=\color{red}{25}$. The right side should be $25$ not $5$.